# Ubuntu 18.04: suggestion for an extension/app that can change the login+desktop+lockscreen wallpaper automatically

Tags: 18.04, customization, desktop-background

using files that are stored locally.

I've looked at

- random wallpaper changer gnome3 - didn't install. looking at the description, it can't do local files
- shotwell - can only do desktop+lockscreen. Plus I need to import my wallpaper to it's library (would like to avoid this)
- variety - does not change lockscreen wallpaper

Any more suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like it to be random, or cycle in a specific order all the time ?
And do you want the same wallpaper or 3 different wallpapers at the same time for each 'screen' ?

Comment: Do you have an app in mind that can do any of what you said? :)

Comment: I don't, but a small script could easily do what you want